# Merging columns while summing values at the same time in R

Tags: r, merge, sum

My question is simple. I'm fairly new to R and I have a few dataframes looking like this:

```
> print(averagetable)
   Group.1 Vigilance   Head-up   Grazing    Browsing     Moving   Grooming Resting      Fleeing
1 cluster1 0.2275285 0.5353896 0.1411797 0.005844156 0.04832251 0.01666667       0 0.0014610390
2 cluster2 0.2718750 0.2506696 0.3174107 0.004241071 0.08125000 0.04174107       0 0.0008928571
3 cluster3 0.3486111 0.4276515 0.1337121 0.012500000 0.03472222 0.01603535       0 0.0027777778
```

I would simply like to perform the following actions:

1) Merging the column `Browsing` into `Grazing` and sum the values for every row. The new column will be named `Feeding`.

2) Merging the column `Fleeing` into `Moving` and sum the values for every row.

3) Merging the columns `Vigilance`, `Grooming` and `Resting` into `Head-up` and sum the values for every row. The new column will be names `Standing still`.

Expected output example (with values instead of formulas):

```
> print(averagetable)
   Group.1             Standing still                    Moving           Feeding     
1 cluster1  sum(Head-up+Vigilance+Resting+Grooming  sum(Fleeing+Moving) sum(Grazing+Browsing)
2 cluster2            "                                    "                    "                    
3 cluster3            "                                     "                   "
```

Could somebody please let me know a compact way to transform the data? Is there a special function to merge and sum column values?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Please add the expected output for the given example.

Comment: @RonakShah Done

Comment: `averagetable$Feeding = averagetable$Grazing + averagetable$Browsing` It's simply summing multiple columns, no merging involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
averagetable <- data.frame(averagetable$Head-up + averagetable$Vigilance + averagetable$Resting + averagetable$Grooming,
                           averagetable$Fleeing + averagetable$Moving,
                           averagetable$Grazing + averagetable$Browsing)
colnames(averagetable) <- c('Standing still','Moving','Feeding')
```

First create a data-frame with your wanted columns and then name them.

Comment: consider using `with` when you find yourself using `df$...` a lot on a single line. `averagetable <- with(averagetable, data.frame(Head-up + Vigilance +...))` . It will save typing and prevent typos.

Comment: You can also name your columns directly with ``data.frame(`Standing still` = ...)``

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments this is just simple summing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
#dplyr option
averageTable %>% mutate(`Standing Still` = sum(Head.up, Vigilance, Resting, Grooming),
                        Moving = sum(Fleeing, Moving),
                        Feeding = sum(Grazing, Browsing)) %>% select(Group.1, `Standing Still`, Moving, Grazing)

#Even better dplyr option thank @moody_mudskipper(I'm not a tidyverse aficionado) 
averageTable %>% transmute(Group.1, `Standing Still` = sum(Head.up, Vigilance, Resting, Grooming),
                        Moving = sum(Fleeing, Moving),
                        Feeding = sum(Grazing, Browsing))

#data.table option
setDT(averageTable)
averageTable[, .(`Standing Still` = sum(Head.up, Vigilance, Resting, Grooming),
             Moving = sum(Fleeing, Moving),
             Feeding = sum(Grazing, Browsing)), by = "Group.1"]
```

Comment: `transmute` might be more appropriate than `mutate` here (it will save typing the column names twice).

Comment: don't forget `Group.1` in the `transmute` call :). You can leave it unnamed.